# How to save and use an object until saveEventually() succeeds in parse?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am working on `localDataStore()` with an android application which uses Parse. I understand that if an object is already in the localDataStore, calling `saveEventually()` updates the object and it will be available with latest changes offline even though it has not been saved yet in the cloud.

What happens if I create a new object and use saveEventually? Tried retrieving with `query.fromPin()` but could not. Is it possible to retrieve and use it??

Answer (score 0):

You find it the same way if it was on the cloud:

query.find(), findInBackground() or if you want, query.fromLocalDataStore()